# bizzare encoding issue makes one specific website gibberish only when viewing source

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, python-requests, hebrew

I'm writing a python script to get articles from a few news websites and i got into a real weird encoding issue. its for an Israeli friend so the websites are all Hebrew, and my method (using requests and beautifulsoup) worked well until i got to this one website that stays gibberish no matter what i do.
the website is [makorishon](https://www.makorrishon.co.il/). the weird thing is this:
its not gibberish when i get it in the browser, the html isn't gibberish when i use "inspect element" on firefox, its not gibberish when i view source from the browser (its not good either, it displays the entire page in two lines between two blocks of js), but it is when i use python, even if to save the html to my computer and then open the saved file in my browser.
i have tried every possible encoding that relates to hebrew in any way, each leaving me with a different set of unintelligible signs.
this is how it looks like normaly:
[image: this is how it should look like]
this is how the saved by python page looks like:
[image: this is how it looks like after saving]
this is the only website that i am aware of that does this, i have used the same tools on other hebrew websites and it came out fine.

the code im using to produce this is:

```
>>> import requests
>>> res = requests.get('https://www.makorrishon.co.il/')
>>> res
<Response [200]>
>>> file = open('makor1.html', 'w')
>>> file.write(res.text)
152957
>>> file.close()
```

this is a linux laptop, btw.

Comment: You're not using `beautifulsoup` when just saving the HTML to a file, correct? The term for what you're seeing is [Mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake). It's probably an inconsistency in the way the page is declaring its encoding.

Comment: Show the code used to produce the problem.

Comment: I am not using beautifulsoup to produce this, and i will show the code although its fairly simple.

Comment: @MarkRansom how does this happen when i pass the code through python and not in the browser?

Comment: `print (res.encoding)` tells me requests thinks this is ISO-8859-1. That is unexpected – it is UTF-8. The content-type meta information is not found, or possibly not parsed correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `res.encoding = 'utf-8'` before writing to the file:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import requests
    res = requests.get('https://www.makorrishon.co.il/')
    res.encoding = 'utf-8'
    file = open('makor1.html', 'wb')
    file.write(res.text.encode('utf-8'))
    file.close()
```

Comment: TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes

Comment: Which Python version are you using? If it's 3.x, you need to open the file with the 'wb' flag, I've updated the code

Comment: didn't know how could do that, its works! the question now is will it pass to Beautifulsoup, but i guess i'll figure it out from here.